# Third connection explanation on BeetleRobot

Tags: voltage

Complete newbie here, so please go easy on me.

I’m working through this guide: https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Build-a-Robot-The-BeetleBot-v2-Revisite/

It mentions “Third Connection” as the super important thing that halves the voltage from 3V to the needed 1.5V, but it doesn’t explain how it works…

> Here is the principal and most important thing about the beetlerobot.
> It is call the "third connection"
>
> In you AA/AAA battery you have 2 wires that provide 3Volts.
>
> In reality, we only use 1,5Volts for both motors.
>
> How can we get half the voltage? Simple, you solder a wire like the
> picture below.

The new wire will touch the last wire you have solder in the last step and you will connect it to the battery holder. See picture.

I’ve had a look around but can’t find anyone else talking about “third connection”. I’ve been through voltage splitting in a LinkedIn course, but that likely won’t work, as the resistors would burn up due to the current. So I’m not sure what to look into here?

I don’t want “Monkey see, monkey do”; I want to learn. Any hints?

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the circuit so that someone answering can reference it, annotate it, etc?

Comment: All I have is the guide. Is there a good tool online for drafting schematics that is preferred to link on this site? so I can help myself get better help? I’m a software developer really, and electricity and electronics are rather new to me

Comment: There's a built-in schematic editor in the post editor - it looks like a little schematic icon and is between the image icon and numbered list icon in the top of the editor.

Comment: Both answers seem like correct and complete answers to your question -  I would recommend using a more rigorous guide to learning EE than this particular build guide. The vague phrasing like "third connection" and "two wires that provide 3v" as well as the lack of a schematic suggests that the post might not necessarily be the best correct/systematic intro to electronics.

Answer (score 4):

They're picking off the wire that connects the batteries together in series to use as a ground for the motor so you can supply it with + and - 1.5V for a simple reversing circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJcIPH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Right. That makes sense to me. So without it, the batteries are in series, meaning 2x1.5V, but with the connection in between, we break the series and get just the 1.5V needed

Comment: That's essentially correct.  The batteries are still in series, but the motor isn't ever connected to the series combination.

Comment: Good point. Important distinction. Alludes to what one of the other answers explain, that there are still 3V voltage in parts of the circuit

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any schematic for the build, which is unfortunate.

The battery holder connects two cells in series, giving you 3 volts:

[image: Battery holder]

A schematic of this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fet8GZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "third connection" described in the tutorial is having you solder a wire to the conductor *between* the two batteries (shown in red box), to tap off 1.5 V.

The equivalent schematic would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLPK1.png)</sup>

The voltage between the red and black wires remains 3 V, while the voltage between the blue and black wires is 1.5 V.

Answer (score 1):

The device comes with simple battery holder which can take two 1.5V cells and connects them in series as there are only two wires out which gives 3V output.

For some reason the device uses 1.5V motors so they can't be run at 3V. So by connecting a third wire in the middle of the batteries, you can have both +1.5V and -1.5V in respect to this third wire. It allows use of 1.5V motors and reversing the direction by connecting either +1.5V or -1.5V to motor via a simple SPDT switch.